# How to get Router Name & IP as shown in Windows Network Tab? (in Code or from Registry)

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, router, ip

Basically, if you go to Start and click Computer and then click on the Network link on the left hand side, you'll notice on the right hand side several categories, one of which is titled "Network Infrustructure", in that category, my router is listed, and in my case, it is "LINKSYS WAG160N Wireless-N ADSL2+ Gateway" and when you right-click and select properties, it lists basic info such as internal/gateway IP address, on mine it is "192.168.1.1"

I would like to know how to retreive this information in ie: either registry location or Windows API call or .net framework reference etc, preferably a Windows API or Registry Location so that i can call it using a legacy VB6 app but anything will do at the moment as i am totally lost in this respect.

thanks guys :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer from a superuser post and here is the link...
https://superuser.com/questions/194862/how-to-get-router-name-ip-as-shown-in-windows-network-tab-in-code-or-from-reg

basically, turns out you need to look into the upnp.dll insite windows\system32 and learn how to use it by looking up references for the upnp api on msdn! this is how you get the details.

Answer (score 1):

You could easily get all the information you need using WMI Network classes.
For a simple .Net code with a full implementation, look [here](http://codehill.com/2009/03/get-the-available-network-connections-using-wmi/).

Comment: thanks for the info, but this just shows the details for my local/client wireless 802.11n wifi card on my computer, this doesn't list or show the actual router, which would be the linksys, i checked through the enumeration.

Comment: Try one of the other WMI classes then. You can still use the code to run through the enumeration

Comment: which WMI class do you think it is likely to be? i'm at a stumbling block!

Answer (score 0):

Did you ask this at SO?  You can parse the output of the "route print -4" to get the default gateway.

Comment: hi dbasnett, i'm trying to get the name of the router that is tied to the particular default gateway/router ip as is shown through the method described above, do you know how to do this? thanks.